# How do I make a widget or a screen appear after a few seconds? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm doing a search history with shared preferences and when you click on the search history the profile of a product with certain information appears.

When the product profile appears there is a star and the star changes color according to whether it is true or false, the problem is that it always appears false.

Whether it is true or false depends on the information or a value that I get from the database.

What I have noticed is that the method that retrieves that value takes a few seconds and that is why the value is always set to false.

I am executing the method that brings me the value in the init state.
In the validation that is inside starbutton I think that favoriteState is different from 1 and therefore false because the method that is in the init state ObtenerEstadoFavorito takes a few seconds while the screen or the star button appears

Is there a way to make the view or the screen appear after a few seconds or what should I do?

```
/////  code  ////

    // this is from class search delegate, the part of search history
     onTap: () {
    
                                        Navigator.push(context,
                                            new MaterialPageRoute(builder:
                                                (context) => new PerfilCliente(this.decodedList[i]))
                                        );
                                      },
    
    class PerfilCliente extends StatefulWidget {
      }
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return perfilclientestate();
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    }
    
    class perfilclientestate extends State<PerfilCliente>{
    String estadofavorito;
    bool estadoiconofavorito;
    List InfoperfilCliente=[];
    
    @override
      void initState() {
    ObtenerEstadoFavorito();
    void ObtenerEstadoFavorito(){
     searchdelegateperfilclienteservices.ObtenerEstadoFavorito(infovalidacionloginmodel2.getIdUsuario(),widget.perfilseleccionado['2']).then((value) =>
            setState(() {
              InfoperfilCliente.addAll(value);
              estadofavorito = InfoperfilCliente[0].IdEstadoFavorito;
    )
        );}
    }
    }
    
    Widget PerfilUsuario(){
    return Container(
    child: StarButton(
     isStarred:  estadofavorito == "1" ? estadoiconofavorito = true : estadoiconofavorito = false,
                        iconSize: 40,
     valueChanged: (value){
                          setState(() {
                            estadoiconofavorito = value;
                          });
    }
    )
    );
    }
    
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              title: Text("name"),
              centerTitle: true
          ),
          body: PerfilUsuario(),
    
        );
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, it is taking time to fetch data from your database so the default value appears first.

in this case we can use `future.delay` function to delay an event from happening for a duration of time. usage of future.delay is simple:

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4), () {
  //write the event you want it to happen after duration of seconds

})
```

you can fetch the data first then use the future.delay on the function that makes your data appears which i think this one `PerfilUsuario()` like this:

```
void PerfilUsuario() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      return Container(
          child: StarButton(
              isStarred: estadofavorito == "1"
                  ? estadoiconofavorito = true
                  : estadoiconofavorito = false,
              iconSize: 40,
              valueChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  estadoiconofavorito = value;
                });
              }));
    });
  }
```

Comment: can i  use the future.delayes in the body: ??. There it shows PerfilUsuario()

Comment: Alright i have edited my answer, try future.delayed inside the function. and specify the seconds as you want

Comment: It doesn't work, the screen goes blank.
Any other solution??

Comment: ok to fully understand, you are getting the value of "estadofavorito" from database, if its 1 then change the value of "estadoiconfavorito" to true right?, 

ok remove the future function and print the "estadofavorito" value in the debugger by using "print(estadofavorito)" above the container and see if the value retrieved correctly from the database.

Comment: I solved it using a future builder , do I mark it as the correct answer or what should I do??

Comment: if my answer solved your problem or at least solved part of your problem you may choose as correct otherwise no need to do anything, thank you anyway